# Вывод переменной из работающего цикла while

Tags: python, циклы

Доброго всем времени суток! Я только не давно занялся программированием на python поэтому прошу сильно не пинать.
В моей программе в функции работает цикл while в этом цикле производятся расчеты, мне нужно постоянно отслеживать состояние одной переменной и на каждой итерации передовать ее значение в другую функцию которая работает паралельно в потоке,возможно ли это сделать и если возожно то как? Я уже неделю голову ломаю и ни чего не могу придумать.

Вот подобный код, только без потоков и он тоже не работает!

```
    def fg():
kloc = ty()
global y
if kloc:                  # Если значения переменной kloc = True (флаг поднят)
    print('Переклчаемся') # то исполняется программа print('Переклчаемся')
    y = 44
elif not kloc:            # Если значения переменной kloc = False (флаг опущен)
    print('Не переклчаемся') # то исполняется программа print('Не переклчаемся')
    y = 55

def ty():
z = 0
x = 0
kloc = False           # Назначем нашим флагом переменную kloc и присваеваем ей
while x < 10:          # значение False (флаг опущен)
    if z == 0:
        z = 1
        x = x + 1
        fg()
    elif z == 1:
        x = x + 1
        kloc = True        # Присваеваем переменной kloc значение True (поднимаем флаг)
        fg()               # Вызываем фукцию проверки флага fg()

ty()
```

Если не создавать функцию  ty() то эта программа работает. Команду return в функцию ty() тоже добовлял, все равно не  работает! Ошибка происходит на этой строке kloc = ty() она просто не чего не передает даже с командой или командами return.
Помогите пожалуйста, что делать не знаю.

Comment: Для начала исправьте отступы, код читать невозможно.

Comment: У меня в коде все с отступами в порядке,это после переноса кода получилось такое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понял ваш замысел, но вам не такое взаимодействие надо?

```
def fg(kloc):
    if kloc: 
        print('Переклчаемся')
        y = 44
    else:
        print('Не переклчаемся') 
        y = 55
    return y

def ty():
    z = 0
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        if z == 0:
            z = 1
            x = x + 1
            y = fg(False)
        elif z == 1:
            x = x + 1
            y = fg(True)

ty()
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли !